Selenium Chromedriver: Prevent stale element exception for span element
I am currently trying to automate the collection of data from a website. The site itself doesn't pause while it's loading data, so I have my program track the displayed number of returned search results after I type in a search query to try and make sure I'm not collecting data before the site has finished loading from its database. Checking the text section where this number is located sometimes gives me a stale reference error.
while TimingLoops < 5:
        TimingLoops = TimingLoops+1
        time.sleep(0.05)
        newelement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]")
        newelementText = newelement.text

Error
Exception has occurred: StaleElementReferenceException
Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame

To prevent the stale reference error, I inserted a line of code to check for the presence of the text that I want. I'm assuming that maybe what's happening is the value in the span disappears during the process of changing? I expected that this line of code would prevent my code from moving forward until the element was present and available to be used. Am I using the wrong expected condition to do this? My knowledge of HTML and python are both pretty limited so maybe this is just the wrong sort of check to use for this element type? I attempted to use a staleness_of check but that cannot be used on a tuple and searching through the list of selenium expected conditions didn't reveal anything that jumped out at me as more suitable than the condition I am using now.
 while TimingLoops < 5:
        TimingLoops = TimingLoops+1
        time.sleep(0.05)
        newelement = WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
 "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]"))
        )
        newelementText = newelement.text

And I still receive the error
Exception has occurred: StaleElementReferenceException
Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame

Will I just have to revert to using an explicit wait of some kind?
This is the website: https://bonap.net/TDC/#
And this is the specific element that I am trying to capture

Edit: Listing the entire code block needed to recreate the error, including the recommended wait condition by JeffC. The error occurs after typing in a search into the search bar, not before, with newcount[0].text throwing a stale element reference exception. Sometimes it can run up to 20 or 30 times before the error is thrown.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://bonap.net/TDC/")

GenusName = "Rudbeckia"
x=1
GenusCount = 0
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while x<100:
    print("The current loop is " + str(x))
    x=x+1
    counts = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#genus-panel div.taxon-panel-description > span")))
    ## This is the number of genera before our search
    print("The original number of genera is " + counts[0].text)
    ## Find the Genus Searchbar, delete its current text, and enter our search again
    GenusSearchBar = WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/input"))
    )
    GenusSearchBar.clear()
    GenusSearchBar.send_keys(GenusName)
    newcount = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#genus-panel div.taxon-panel-description > span")))
    ## This is the number of genera after we search
    print("The new count is " + newcount[0].text)


Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted. This includes error messages.

Ah, sorry. Will do!

Your code looks fine. Can you share the URL? Is the page constantly reloading? Something does seem strange.

Alright, I've included the URL of the site and a screenshot of the element in question to hopefully make things as clear as possible. The site doesn't seem to reload when I type into the search box.

I'm not experiencing the issues that you are. This is code that I wrote and it's working. I ran it five times with no issues or errors.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://bonap.net/TDC/#'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
counts = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#genus-panel div.taxon-panel-description > span")))
print(f'genera: {counts[0].text}')
print(f'species: {counts[1].text}')

and it prints
genera: 3625
species: 24184


NOTE: I just realized... you are using EC.presence_of_element_located(). Presence means the element is in the DOM but does not guarantee that it's visible or ready to be interacted with. That could be causing your issue.
If you need to click an element, use EC.element_to_be_clickable(). If you need to interact with an element, e.g. .text, .send_keys, etc., then use EC.visibility_of_element_located(). Generally I would avoid waiting for presence unless you are doing something specific where you are NOT going to interact with the element and you know what you're doing.

A stale element is an element reference stored in a variable that no longer exists because the page has reloaded or changed. For example
e = driver.find_element(...)
driver.refresh() # this wipes out the reference stored in 'e'
e.click() # this throws a stale element exception

The way to avoid stale elements is to make sure the page is stable/loaded before scraping the page. In this case, the code was running faster than the page and the search takes a second to load so your code was grabbing a reference, then the page reloaded, then you accessed that reference throwing the exception. The fix is to grab a reference, do the search, wait for the reference to go stale using EC.staleness_of(), now wait for the desired element, then access the element.
I've updated the code to take care of the stale element exception and add a loop of search terms.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://bonap.net/TDC/#'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

genera = ["Rudbeckia","Abelia","Abies"]

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for genus in genera:
    count = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#genus-panel div.taxon-panel-description > span")))

    search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "genus-filter")))
    search.clear()
    search.send_keys(genus)
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(count))
    count = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#genus-panel div.taxon-panel-description > span")))
    print(f'genus <{genus}> count: {count.text}')

This outputs:
genus <Rudbeckia> count: 1
genus <Abelia> count: 1
genus <Abies> count: 1


Potential solution for the occasional stale element exception... turn
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(count))

into
try:
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(count))
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(count))
except TimeoutException:
    # ignore and move on

and add the import
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


Thank you! I implemented your suggestion but still seem to be getting an error. I've added the entire code block needed to recreate the error instead of the small snippet from before. Sometimes the code can run for a few iterations before throwing the stale element exception and it only occurs after searching for the number of genera listed. When the page initially loads I am able to get that information without any issues

@SamanthaClark I've updated my answer to explain what a stale element is, how to avoid it, and then updated my code with the fixes and added a loop for genera search terms.

Firstly, I want to deeply thank you for your patience with me. I saw that you reformatted some parts of my question that I set up incorrectly, and also you put the effort into helping me learn rather than just throwing a solution at me. That's incredibly helpful and kind, so thank you so much!
I had some idea that I needed to let things go stale and then try to check, but I've still got a lot to learn and was stumped on how to go about handling this problem for a while. Your solution works beautifully! I know I've said this twice already, but thank you for all of your help!

I have noticed that while this is vastly improved, it still sometimes throws the stale element exception. I can have it run in a loop somewhere between 500-1000 times over the course of a few minutes as opposed to only 3-5 times with what I had, but the exception still pops up every now and then. It's rare enough that it isn't a problem, but I'm curious if there are ever points in webscraping where you are forced to use a static pause like time.sleep() to allow the website time to load and stabilize? Or if there's always a more elegant solution?

Yes, I was actually considering that in this case. I usually try to find as many clever ways to wait as I can think of using a proper wait (WebDriverWait) but sometimes I just can't find one and have to give up and use a sleep. If you do add a sleep, I would put it after the staleness check.

When it does throw the stale element exception, what line is it on? The count.text? I wonder if the typing sometimes triggers the search part way through and then triggers another search afterwards, e.g. starts after "Rud" then starts again after "beckia". In that case elements actually go stale twice. If that's the case, I think I have a potential solution that I've added to the bottom of my answer. Let me know if that makes sense.

I think that helps! But the two wait until staleness commands didn't work until I put in a wait until visible for the element. It just went through the two of them immediately, I assume since if count was stale already then the time to check it a second time was only a few milliseconds and not long enough for the staleness of the count element to change
